# Make static pages and NOT appear as blog

Tags: wordpress

I have just installed wordpress, and finally found out how to fix the issue that wordpress works as a blog as default. This was not what I wanted, since I want to create a site. I changed the front page to be static. Now when I create a new page, I want this to be a static page too, and not a blog. A new page keeps appearing as a blog. How can I change this?

Comment: As a side note... the fact that WordPress works/acts as a blog is not an issue. It's a blogging engine you're using as a CMS for static pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Template page for it.

You can check here :- `http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates`